# How to make generic type of specifically annotated class?

Tags: java, spring, generics, hibernate-envers

I need to generify an interface to a class that is annotated to a specific annotation, say having the following entity class

```
@Entity
@Audited
class Record {
   private Long id;
   private String something;
   private String somethingElse;
}
```

which is audited with Hibernate Envers, I want to provide a service class that obtains some revision data. With something like

```
public interface AuditRecordService<E extends Audited> {
//
}
```

I know I can modify the `Record` class to extend an abstract class, something like:

```
@Entity
@Audited
class Record extends RevisionedEntity {
...
```

This works for me, but I want to avoid unnecessary extension, since it's already annotated with `@Audited`. Is it possible to reuse this annotation as a generic type?

Comment: No.  There is no way to require that a supertype or generic type argument has a particular annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Audited` is an annotation, not a type.  Annotations cannot be extended, so the only possible implementation of `AuditRecordService<E extends Audited>` would be `AuditRecordService<Audited>`, which would be pretty useless.